# TypeError: superclass must be a Class (Module given)

Tags: ruby

I have a class which inherits another class

```
Class A
end

Class A::B < A
end
```

I am trying to write specs for class B by describing it as:

```
describe A::B, type: :class do
 #some test here
end
```

But i get this error: TypeError: superclass must be a Class (Module given)
on spec file'd describe line.
How can i fix this?

Comment: when creating a class, you can't inherit from a module.

Comment: There are some glaring problems with this code. `Class` is not a keyword so Ruby will think you're trying to call a method called `Class`. Defining a nested class/module with the scope resolution operator (`::`) is problematic since it doesn't reopen the class/module and set the correct module nesting. Use `class A; class B; end; end`. Beyond that I think you have actually previously defined A or you have a naming confict with an existing constant.

Comment: `A` is defined as as `Module` somewhere. What you have presented will not reproduce the error you are experiencing.

Answer (score -2):

Your actual class A and Module A confusing you.

Try add folder A in your sepc folder and directly describe class 'B' instead of using module with class `A::B`. It will work.

`/spec/A/B.rb`

```
describe B, type: :class do
 #some test here
end
```

Comment: The spec has nothing to do with the issue here which is that the OP is reopening a class with the wrong keyword.